# Finding ROI in image using wavelets

Tags: image-processing, roi, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I have an image obtained by phone camera and I need to find regions, where balls are. An image can for example look like this:

[image: Image example]

I tried segmentation, but results are not as good as I would like.

My current idea is:

In 1D, when i have ball, I can use continuous wavelet transform with Morlet wavelet to find it. There are images of 1D CWT of ball signal:
[image: 1D signal of ball]

And this signal CWT with Morlet wavelet looks like this:
[image: CWT of 1D ball signal]
(Note: image is stretched in Y direction)

Can I use something simillar in image? Does something like 2D CWT exists? If it does, is it somewhere implemented (C++)? Or is there better solution?

Thanks for your time

---

EDIT (comment reply to YvesDaoust):

Here you can see result of OpenCV HoughCircles. As you can see, result completely doesn't fit balls.

[image: OpenCV HoughCircles result]

---

EDIT 2 (comment reply to YvesDaoust):

I have modified Canny threshold parameter and set center threshold value (param2 in OpenCV implementation) to 1. These are first 300 circles. Still too many false positives.

[image: OpenCV HoughCircles result 2]

Comment: What about a Hough transform ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's useless. Unless the one implemented in OpenCV. It founds too much false positives and takes too much time.

Comment: Tune the radius parameter.

Comment: @YvesDaoust which operation apply on image before HoughCircles?

Comment: None, there is a built-in gradient.

Comment: @YvesDaoust see edit. Any suggestions to improve?

Comment: This result is quite abnormal. Are you somehow transforming the image ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust i have changed param1 and param2 (were default before). See edit 2 for result. Still too many false positives and it's slow. But already makes sense.

Comment: I can't understand those false positives vs. so many false negatives...

Comment: @YvesDaoust what do you mean you don't understand? Why are they there? Why not all balls are identified?

Comment: Inappropriate parameter settings or some bug in your code. Why do the images appear in pseudocolors ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust it's colormap: matplotlib.pyplot.imshow default colormap (viridis).

No image filtering, nothing like this, just loading as greyscale.
Python code enclosed:
cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=int(round(5*pxPerMm)), param1=50, param2=1, minRadius=int(round(2.5*pxPerMm)), maxRadius=int(round(10*pxPerMm))).
Minimal diameter of balls is 5mm, maximal is 20.

Comment: Try to tune param1, param2.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you. I had to use CLAHE and tune param1 and it workes. But please, do you know some way, how automatically set param1 based on input image?

Comment: This is very difficult as the image has other content than what you are looking at so it should be adaptive. You can try some multiple of the average gradient intensity.